# how to install fatjar in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

Is there anyway to install `fatjar` plugin in `eclipse` `mars`.
I used this plugin in `eclipse` `ganymede`.

if it is not possible is there any alternative for this plugin?
fatjar site : http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

both way not working:

1. extract/copy to plugin folder and run with -clean
2. use update url

**UPDATE:**

result when installing with update url:

An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=D__Programs_eclipse_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]net.sf.fjep.fatjar 0.0.31, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]net.sf.fjep.fatjar 0.0.31.

Comment: Edit the question to include the details of what happens when you try.

Comment: Have you read the discussion [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/fjep/discussion/?source=navbar)?

Comment: @E-Riz question updated, I found one Chinese site that generate version 0.0.32 that works with Luna but doesn't work with mars

Comment: @greg-449 link doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution:

first need to install : Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support

You can get it from Update URL: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5

after eclipse restarted, we can install the fatjar plugin with update URL

or

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18r_gETeXffYh1vo900c74rlCFa3fqv8R/view  download it  from  here,  after  install   restart  eclipse

Comment: Works, thanks. Update URL: `http://kurucz-grafika.de/fatjar` See also: `https://sourceforge.net/p/fjep/discussion/396532/thread/4edb64ed/` for another reference.

Comment: I think it's not possible anymore with recent versions of Eclipse (mine is 4.14)... Last update-site to propose 2.0 Style Plugin Support is http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7 but impossible to install Fatjar then.